# Trace theorem for manifolds with boundary

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis

Can I get a reference to a trace theorem for a manifold $M$ with boundary $\partial M$, and I am hoping the inequality
$$\lVert Tu \rVert_{L^2(\partial M)} \leq c\lVert u \rVert_{H^1(M)}$$
will hold.

What does the manifold need to satisfy for it to hold?
Thanks

Comment: If the manifold  $M$ is  smooth and  the boundary is compact then  it certainly holds.   It also holds in certain noncompact situations if  $M$ and $\partial M$ have bounded geometry at $\infty$.

Comment: For `$M$` compact with smooth boundary, you can find this in Proposition 4.5 in volume I of the 3-volume monograph of M.E. Taylor on Partial Differential Equations.

Comment: Does $M$ really need to $C^\infty$ smooth like Taylor demands?

Comment: No soup89, the manifold need not be $C^\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

The book  by Robert A. Adams has a 'ultimate' theorem about: trace theorem (resctricting to lower dimensions), extension theorem (extending to higher dimensions) and sobolev embedding.

It is Theorem 7.58. It is definitely more than you need here. It involves even fractional order Sobolev spaces.

The theorem is about Euclidean spaces. If you want a manifold version, we can always do it by hand. (Or just by waving your hand, especially when you are not really interested in controlling the constant.) Chop the manifold into pieces near the boundary and consider a coordinate system mapping a neighborhood to (a domain of ) half space, then use the partition of unity. The constant in your final inequality depends on a uniform bound of the coordinate system. Sorry, I can not be very precise here. However, the method works.

Comment: Which edition of Adams are you referring to ?